# Magento - Block/layout issues with addPriceBlockType

Tags: php, magento

I am having a little trouble with the addPriceBlockType in Magento.

I am trying to extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price for configurable products only.  I want to define my own block type and template which handle prices for configurable products.

In my modules layout file I have the following:

```
    <default>
      <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>configurable</type>
        <block>myblocktype/product_price</block>
        <template>myblocktype/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
  </default>
```

The price block disappears from the configurable products - which suggests I am heading in the right direction - but the block is never output.  Further, the _toHtml method in my custom block is never reached with the above layout XML.  My custom block is extending  Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price.

If however, I supply a block type of Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price in my layout xml as in:

```
    <default>
      <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>configurable</type>
        <block>catalog/product_price</block>
        <template>myblocktype/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
  </default>
```

The the block is output, with my custom template.

I need a custom block type though so this inst a good enough solution.

Can anyone advise on why my custom block will not output but the core block does using identical layout xml.  Also I am using the same method as the core bundle and msrp modules use.

I am running this code on Magento CE 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445330/drew) (OP) already self-answered the question.

Quote:

> EDIT: Issue sorted. Was a naming issue.

<sub>Note: It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. Please just post it as an real answer, but *not* in a question or comment. Posting as real answer helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear (avoids making other people wasting their time).</sub>